# Studying the convergence of $f_n(z)=\frac{\cos(\sqrt{nz})}{\sqrt{n+2z}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Study the convergence of the following sequence $f_n(z)=\frac{\cos(\sqrt{nz})}{\sqrt{n+2z}}$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\cos(\sqrt{nz})}{\sqrt{n+2z}}=0$

Then:

$|\frac{\cos(\sqrt{nz})}{\sqrt{n+2z}}-0|=\leqslant|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2z}}|\leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\to 0$

**Questions**:

Is this resolution right? Can I use $\cos z\leqslant 1$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your definition of $\sqrt z?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $z\in\mathbb C$ you don't have $|\cos z| \le 1$. We have

$$ \cos(x+iy) = \cos x \cosh y - i \sin x \sinh y $$
$$ |\cos(x+iy)| = \sqrt{\cos^2 x \cosh^2 y + \sin^2 x\sinh^2 y}= \sqrt{\sinh^2 y + \cos^2 x} = \sqrt{\cosh^2 y - \sin^2 x}$$
so $$ \sinh (|{\rm Im}\, z|)\le |\cos z| \le \cosh ({\rm Im}\, z)$$
and for big $n$:
$$|\cos(\sqrt{n} z)| \approx \frac12\exp(\sqrt{n}|{\rm Im}\,z|) $$
You can use that to show that this sequence is not convergent for ${\rm Im}\,z \neq 0$.

For ${\rm Im}\, z =0$ your proof is mostly fine, except for the last inequality which is true for all $n\in\mathbb N$ only for ${\rm Re}\,z \ge 0$. For ${\rm Re}\,z < 0$ you still have $|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2z}}| \rightarrow 0$, but you need to use a different argument: $$ |\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2z}}| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{|1+\frac{2z}{n}|}} \rightarrow 0 \cdot 1 =1$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What kind of argument can I use on this case?

Comment: @Pedro Gomes I've edited my answer to match the clarification that $z\in\mathbb C$.